# How can i stop a loop when break does not work?

Tags: python, list, loops, break

```
x=[]
while True:
    try:
        x.append(float(input('what are your numbers?\n')))
        if x.append('done'):
            break
    except:
        print('bad data')
        continue
print(len(x), sum(x), min(x), max(x))
```

In this code I want the user to provide numbers, skip strings and finally I want the loop when the user types in 'done' but it does not work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot make a float of the string 'done' so the code goes to the except and continues looping

Comment: What do you expect `if x.append('done'):` to do? ` By the way, bare `except:` statements like this are bad practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the input value to a variable first, so you can use it for the comparison and cast to float.

```
x=[]

while True:
    inp = input('what are your numbers?\n')
    if inp == 'done':
        break
    try:
        x.append(float(inp))   
    except ValueError:
        print('bad data')

print(len(x), sum(x), min(x), max(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does not break when the input is `"done"

```
    if x.append('done'):
        break
```

This appends the string "done" to the list `x`.  `append` returns `None`, so your condition is *always* `False`.  `break` will work just fine -- you have to write your code to get there.  Check the input for validity before you convert to float.  During this process, check for "done":

```
    user_input = input('what are your numbers?\n')
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    # Continue checking the input
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check first if the input is `'done'` before inserting to your list, because `max` will raise `TypeError` if any of list elements is not a number. Also `continue` is unnecessary in your implementation because it is last the statement in your loop:

```
x=[]
while True:
    try:
        data = input('what are your numbers?\n')
        if data == 'done':
            break
        else:
            num = float(data)
            x.append(num)
    except:
        print('bad data')

print(len(x), sum(x), min(x), max(x))
```